# fixed element by absolute position in all browsers?

Tags: css, position

I have this piece of HTML code :

```
<aside>
<div class="cover"></div>
<header>
    <div> ... </div>
</header>
</aside>
```

and my CSS :

```
aside { 
    max-width:500px;
    width:30%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    background:#000;
    overflow:hidden; 
}
.cover { 
    background:url('../img/cover-1.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size:cover;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

I want to have `aside` fixed to the body not only to viewport.
I tried to figure out how [medium.com](http://www.medium.com) has done it but I couldn't ...
my situation is much similar to medium.com, anybody can help me ?
EDIT: I searched about it, they said add `position:relative` to body tag, but when I add it, `aside` disappears !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The simplest way I can think of:**

[***Live demo***](http://jsbin.com/EjiRUtOR/4/)

[image]

```
<div id="container">  
  <aside>(Menu at the bottom)</aside>  
  <section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</section>
</div>
```

```
body{
    overflow:hidden;            /* Don't scroll please */
}

aside, section{                 /* Note the common properties */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
}   

aside{
    background: url("bg.jpg") center center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 30%;                 /* note */ 
}    
section{
    margin-left: 30%;           /* note */
    overflow: auto;             /* Scroll this guy */
}
```

***[Better Demo with content (with width) and `aside`'s bottom menu](http://jsbin.com/EjiRUtOR/6/)***

Comment: Nice Roko, your idea of removing `cover` div and `overflow:hidden` on body tag helped me solve my problem. thank you so much :)

Comment: @Pay4m you're welcome! Here is another demo if you want to restrict the width of the `section`'s content; and a view of the bottomed `aside`'s menu: http://jsbin.com/EjiRUtOR/6/

Comment: @Pay4m oh, great! I've added the example any way, to spare to someone additional headaches ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/QzdCT/4/

You should be able to modify it here and there to fit what you need.

Three divs - One parent, and two siblings.

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='aside'></div>
    <div class='mainBody'></div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS -

```
.container{
    height:500px;
}
.aside
{
    height:500px;
    width:40%;
    background:#9e9e9e;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
}
.mainBody
{
    height:500px;
    width:59%;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: but with adding `height:500px` to the parent `container`, the aside is not fixed to viewport ! even adding `height:100%` doesn't fix it ..

Comment: let me change the main question! how can we set `height:100%` 100% of whole screen or body ? not just 100% of the viewport ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your child div cover is covering it

try keeping everything the same but just changing this:

```
.cover {
    left: 30%;
}
```